# how does a web page prevent Chrome tab from being closed by the user

Tags: google-chrome

I was surfing the web with Chrome and landed on a page that suddenly displayed an alert stating that my computer may have been infected with malware, and there was a mechanical voice instructing me to phone an 866 phone number. When I tried to close the tab, it wouldn't close; nor would the alert.  I had to terminate the Chrome processes in Windows Task Manager.

How does a web page manage to control the tab so that it does not respond to mouse-clicks? I would have expected that Chrome would not allow that to happen.

Comment: just someone abusing an `onunload` handler

Comment: I see that `onbeforeunload` is a  cancelable event.